# Probability space problem

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

Given:$( \Omega ,F,\mu)$- probability space.
$f:\Omega\rightarrow X'. X$-is a Banach space, such that the mapping  $\Omega\ni\omega\mapsto\langle x, f(\omega)\rangle\in L^1(\Omega,\mu)$ for all $\ x\in X$. Prove that the mapping $ X\ni x \mapsto\  \int_\Omega^\ \mathrm\langle x, f(\omega)\rangle\mathrm{d}\mu (\omega)$ defines an element in $X'$ which we denote by $\int_\Omega^\ f{d}\mu.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a map

$$T : X \rightarrow L^1(\Omega, \mu), x \mapsto \langle x, f(\cdot) \rangle.$$

By assumption, this map is well-defined.

Check that it satisfies the hypothesis of the closed graph theorem and conculde that it is continuous.

Why does that imply your claim?